# C# eBay API Upload Return Label

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, ebay-api

I haven't been able to figure out how to properly upload a label onto eBay using the /post-order/v2/return/{returnId}/file/upload call.  I keep getting "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.".

I believe it may have to do with the image encoding, but I am not entirely certain.  I was already able to approve the return with POST /return/{returnId}/decide but the next step in uploading is the problem.  I have the image data saved as a base 64 string in a database.  I know the data is good, because in other calls I am able to transform that base 64 string into an image in my application.  So the data from the image isn't in question.  The thing is on http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/post-order/post-order_v2_return-returnId_file_upload__post.html#samplesellerlabel it states that the image data should be "base64-encoded binary representation of the file".

So is it possible that the data I received when grabbing the image with Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes) is not what I actually need?  There are little to no examples on how to do this particular call in C# and I've tried so many things.  I've checked the JSON syntax and it looks to be correct.  (I've removed a large portion of the string as it is too large.)

{"fileName":"5074119065_shippingLabel.jpeg","data":"R0lGODlhCAewBIEAAAAAAP///wAAAAAAACH/C05...zR2On54kkB4nfJYrLFRAAOw==","filePurpose":"LABEL_RELATED"}

I'm fairly convinced that the image data is somehow not formatted correctly, but I'm just not sure. If anyone has any experience with this call I'd appreciate your help. Below is my code and the error comes up on the last line.  The headers and the JSON code has worked without any issues on other eBay calls which is also a reason I suspect my problem may have to do with the formatting of the image data.

```
string url = "https://api.ebay.com/post-order/v2/return/" + returnId + "/file/upload";

        var cancelOrderRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        cancelOrderRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "TOKEN " + authToken);
        cancelOrderRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        cancelOrderRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        cancelOrderRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID", "EBAY_US");
        cancelOrderRequest.Method = "POST";

        string fileName = returnId + "_shippingLabel.jpeg";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cancelOrderRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"fileName\":\"" + fileName + "\",\"data\":\"" + labelData + "\",\"filePurpose\":\"LABEL_RELATED" + "\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)cancelOrderRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. The eBay documentation appears to be inconsistent.  In the top part of the documentation page you linked for the [Upload Return File](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/post-order/post-order_v2_return-returnId_file_upload__post.html) method call, it seems to indicate that the `data` part of the JSON should be an *array* of strings, not just a single string.

> **Payload model**
>
> The following lists *all fields that could be included* in the request.
>
> ```
> { /* UploadFileRequest */
> "data": [
>     string
>     /* More string nodes here */
>   ],
> "fileName": string,
> "filePurpose": token
> }
> ```

But in the JSON sample they show on the same page, the `data` is clearly a single string like you have it in your code.  (Notice the square brackets are missing.)

> **URL format**. See also the [non-wrapped](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/post-order/Samples/post-order_v2_return-returnId_file_upload__post_basic_in_url_json.txt) version of this URL.
>
> ```
> POST https://api.ebay.com/post-order/v2/return/5000124931/file/upload
> {
>   "fileName" : "jasmine.jpeg",
>   "data" : "SGVyZSBpcyB5b3VyIHJld...YWNraW5nIG51bWJlciBpcyAxMjM0NTY3ODk4NzY1",
>   "filePurpose" : "ITEM_RELATED"
> }
> ```

I would try changing it to an array to match the documented payload.  I'm guessing the sample is probably wrong here.

Also, I would **highly** recommend using a JSON serializer like [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) rather than hand-rolling your own JSON, as it is very easy to get the formatting wrong, which will just end up giving you more "400 Bad Request" headaches. Instead, try making the JSON by using an anonymous object and then serializing it, like this:

```
var payload = new 
{
    fileName = returnId + "_shippingLabel.jpeg",
    data = new List<string> { labelData },
    filePurpose = "LABEL_RELATED"
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but sadly changing it to a string array did not work. I did change it to use the Json Serialization which is something I'll use going forward.  But still couldn't get it to work when using your example.

Comment: OK, thanks for giving it a try.  Sorry to hear that it did not work out.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov I never found a solution to this problem and I abandoned trying to find a solution after MANY different tries.

Comment: @Roro it seem to work for me if I encode PDF file twice with base64, provide it as string, not array, and provide filename.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Could you provide a sample of your code?